# Blood flow with various sized tubing

Tags: flow

We are dealing with an issue I would like some help with.   We have 1/4 inch cannulas in a patient connected to 1/4 tubing to a centrifugal pump for cardiopulmonary support.    If we change the 1/4 inch tubing to 3/8 inch tubing ( but leave the 1/4 inch cannulas in the patient which drain into the tubing) will we get better flow?

Comment: You may get more turbulence at the transition, which I suspect can be bad for blood cells. I can't help thinking that, for life-critical questions, you should be asking this question on a website frequented by healthcare professionals.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is biology or healthcare much more than physics.

Comment: @JonCuster I don't know what is "cannula", "cardiopulmonary support" and "tubing" in this context. But beside these, it seems to me on-topic, but I can't decide in the lack of knowledge. So I have to click "skip".

Comment: Seems to me the question is basically asking about the flow rate between two tubes, but what "better" in this medical context means is not clear to me. It also should go without needing to be said, but *Whatever the answer given by someone about the flow rates, we cannot (and should not) say anything about whether it's a good idea; that should be left for a medical professional.*

Comment: It's a physics question but others are right, you shouldn't be taking advice from non-medical people. From an engineering point of view though, changing the 1/4" for  3/8" diameter tubing between the pump and catheter  could potentially increase head at the catheter connection and thus increase catheter flow rate, but not significantly if the connecting tube is short. It depends on length whether you would have significant advantage.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your flow rates are slow enough that the flow is non-turbulent. In that case the relevant equation is the Hagen-Poiseuille equation:

$$ \text{Flow rate} = \frac{\pi }{8 \eta } \frac{\Delta P}{\ell} r^4 $$

In this equation $r$ is the internal radius of the tubing, $\eta$ is the viscosity and $\Delta P/\ell$ is the pressure drop per metre along the tube. I think that a centrifugal blood pump generates a constant pressure $\Delta P$, and presumably the length of the tubing, $\ell$, is constant so in that case we get:

$$ \text{Flow rate} \propto r^4 $$

and increasing the internal radius of the tube by even a small amount will make a big difference. There will still be a bottleneck at the cannula, but if the length of the cannula is small compared to the total length of the tubing you'll still see a big increase in flow rate.

But this assumes that the restricting factor is the internal diameter of the tube. If this isn't the case then you won't see as big an improvement as you expect. It isn't possible to say for certain without looking at the setup you're using.

Comment: Hi John. If I recall the Poiseuille equation doesn't necessarily work for a non-Newtonian fluid, and assumes linear shear in the fluid. Blood of sufficient Hct is non-Newtonian.  Anyone doing blood flow work should confirm the theory with experiment for their specific hardware.

Comment: @docscience yes, good point. For a non-Newtonian fluid the HP equation will still apply but the viscosity used in the equation will be a function of flow rate not a constant. Offhand I don't know how non-Newtonian blood is in the low flow rate regime.